# Request failed ({:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], :closed}]})

Tags: hex, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying phoenix-trello, and was occurred an error with `mix deps.get`.
Is this the web connect error? Then, what should I do for this error?

```
[root@api phoenix-trello]# erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source-6dc93c1] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
[root@api phoenix-trello]# elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source-6dc93c1] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.3.3



[root@api phoenix-trello]# mix deps.get
Running dependency resolution
* Getting hound (Hex package)
  Checking package (https://repo.hex.pm/tarballs/hound-1.0.2.tar)
Request failed ({:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], :closed}]})
** (Mix) Package fetch failed and no cached copy available
```

Comment: Similar but apparently no definitive answer yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620111/connection-closed-strange-error-unable-to-connect-from-erlang-vm-to-certain-h

Comment: (please don't develop as root... ;-)). What does `curl -v https://repo.hex.pm/tarballs/hound-1.0.2.tar` give you? To rule out any network issues rather than Elixir/Erlang problems?

Comment: `[root@api repo]# curl -v https://repo.hex.pm/tarballs/hound-1.0.2.tar
* About to connect() to repo.hex.pm port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 151.101.17.5... connected
* Connected to repo.hex.pm (151.101.17.5) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5938
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error`

Comment: @cdegroot I dont know  is this format clear, Its obviously answer, that is connect error. But I copy this link to my browser its normal download.

Comment: So at least it happens with Curl as well, which makes it not-an-Elixir-or-Erlang problem. Are you working on a virtual machine? In other words, is the browser on the same host as where you executed this command?

(someone with more SO karma probably should flag this as off-topic and/or properly tag this message when we know more about Carey's setup)